# How to implement a Wrapper class for the Outlook Inspectors correctly

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

C#, VSTO, Outlook 2016
I found the [Connect class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/pia/how-to-implement-a-wrapper-for-inspectors-and-track-item-level-events-in-each-inspector). But I always get a IDE1007 error when I try to hook up the NewInspector event.

```
public class Connect
{
private Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;
private List<OutlookInspector> inspectorWindows;

inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(inspectors_NewInspector);

void inspectors_NewInspector(Outlook.Inspector Inspector) {
  // Check to see if this is a new window you don't already track
  OutlookInspector existingWindow = FindOutlookInspector(Inspector);
  if ( existingWindow == null ) {
    AddInspector(Inspector);
  }
}
```

Apparently inspectors is not found. What am I missing here?
Later on in the OutlookInspector.FindOutlookInspector method the Window variable is not found:

```
private OutlookInspector FindOutlookInspector(object window) {
  foreach ( OutlookInspector inspector in inspectorWindows ) {
    if ( inspector.Window == window ) {
      return inspector;
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, of course - `inspectors.NewInspector +=` line is outside of any method. I suspect it must be inside the constructor:

```
public Connect(Outlook.Inspectors Inspectors)
{
    inspectors = Inspectors;
    inspectorWindows = new List<OutlookInspector>();
    inspectors.NewInspector += new Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(inspectors_NewInspector);
}
```

You would then need to construct an instance of the `Connect` class and pass `Application.Inspectors` to it.

Comment: Hah, yesss, now I got it. With this little hint things are getting forward. Thank you Dmitry.

Comment: If the post answers your question, please mark it as such. Thanks!